# how to include one phphtml code to another php code

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

This is the voting code (this is from voting project index.php page.) include

```
 <?php
/**
Display the results from the database
**/
$q = "SELECT * FROM post";
$r = mysql_query($q);

if(mysql_num_rows($r)>0): //table is non-empty
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
        $net_vote = $row['liked'] - $row['dislike']; //this is the net result of voting up and voting down
?>
</head>
</body>
<div class='entry'>

    <span class='link'>
        <a href='<?php echo $row['link']; ?>'> <?php echo $row['text']; ?> </a>
    </span>
    
    <span class='votes_count' id='votes_count<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'><?php echo $net_vote." votes"; ?></span>
    
    <span class='vote_buttons' id='vote_buttons<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
        <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Up!</a>
        <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Down!</a>
    </span>
    
</div>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

to my blog code ( this is from my own index.php page which shows blog posts )

```
// if post is not submitted display them all
$query = mysql_query("SELECT text, id, link,liked,dislike FROM post ORDER BY id DESC"); 
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$text =  $row['text'];
$vote = $row['liked'] ;
$vote2= $row['dislike'];
$lnk =$row['link'];
$id1 = $row['id'];
        $net_vote = $row['liked'] - $row['dislike'];
echo  '<div id="posts">'.'<h3>Κάποιος είπε:</h3>'.'<p><b><font size="3px">' 
. strip_tags($text) . '</font></b>'.' '. $net_vote .' '.'</p></div><hr><br><br>' 


;

}

}
```

so what I want is in every blog post below the text show thumbs up thumbs down thing. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `include "first-file-name.php";`

or `include "first-file.html";` in the position where you want to include the second file in first file.

in the second file.

In your case, use the second file within the first one.